# Select all but / Delete rows which exist for every ID

Tags: mysql, sql, bigdata

I have a table:

### Table

---

```
  RoomID   Name   Class   Gender
1  A       John    CS     Male
2  A       Mike    EE     Male
3  A       Mili    PD     Female
4  B       John    CS     Male
5  B       Mili    PD     Female
6  C       John    CS     Male
```

---

I want to Select all rows expect those where their (Name, Class) exist for *x*% or more of the ID's, meaning if *x* = 100 and a certain (NameA, ClassA) exists for every ID in the table than filter the rows where Name = NameA and Class = ClassA out.

for example: if *x* = 100, than rows 6,4,1 should be deleted. (John, CS) exist for every ID - A,B,C.
result:

```
  RoomID   Name   Class   Gender
2  A       Mike    EE     Male
3  A       Mili    PD     Female
5  B       Mili    PD     Female
```

if *x* = 60, than rows 3,5 now need to be deleted too. (Mili, PD) exist for IDs A,B therefor exist for 67% of the IDs.
result:

```
  RoomID   Name   Class   Gender
2  A       Mike    EE     Male
```

*notice that I don't have any information outside of the table, I only know for which columns I check the values (Name,Class) in this case.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the proportion of total room ids with a given combo using:

```
select name, class, count(*) as cnt, count(*) / numrooms as p
from t cross join
     (select count(distinct roomid) as numrooms from t) x
group by name, class;
```

You can then use this for deletion:

```
delete t
     from t join
          (select name, class, count(*) as cnt, count(*) / numrooms as p
           from t cross join
                (select count(distinct roomid) as numrooms from t) x
           group by name, class
          ) tt
          on tt.name = t.name and tt.class = t.class
     where p >= 0.7;
```